# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am using Backbone-Relational, and I recieve the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined
```

When I access the `show_note` route.

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'note/:_id': 'show_note'
  },

  show_note: function(_id) {
    console.log('this is the show_note route for _id: ' + _id);
    var note = new App.Models.Note.findOrCreate({ _id: _id });
    var note_view = new App.Views.main_note({ model: note });
    note.fetch();
  }
});
```

The console.log recieves the '_id'. But when I attempt to instantiate `var note`, I recieve the error. How do I fix this?

**EDIT 1**

Adding the Note model:

```
App.Models.Note = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  urlRoot: '/notes',
  idAttribute: '_id',
  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'tags',
    relatedModel: 'App.Models.Tag',
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'note',
      includeInJSON: '_id'
    }
  }]
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Stacktrace added

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your Models.note definition?

Comment: Do you have an `App.Models.Tag` in the global scope?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace to go with that exception?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing `findOrCreate()`, and ended up retrieving the model data like so:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'note/:_id': 'show_note'
  },

  show_note: function(_id) {
    var note = new App.Models.Note({ _id: _id });
    note.fetch({
      success: function(data) {
        var mainNoteView = new App.Views.main_note({ model: note });
        $('#mainNote').append( mainNoteView.render().el );
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```